# embed an image with url aura component

Tags: visualforce, lightning-aura-components, aura, dynamic-visualforce

Is it possible to display an image that has a URL link embedded in it within an Aura Component?

I am able to get the image to display in my lightning page, but I would like to have the image embedded with a URL that takes the user to our app.

This is what I currently have. Ideally I would like the image to be the label.

```
<aura:component implements="flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes" access="global"> 
 <div class="slds-box slds-theme_default">
<img src="{!$Resource.FlowLogo_Power_by}" value="www.salesforce.com"/> 
<ui:outputURL value="website.com" label="CompanyApp"  />
</div>
</aura:component>
```

Comment: By the way, ui components are deprecated and shouldn't be used in new code.

Answer (score 2):

That's just a normal `<a>` element:

```
<a href="https://website.com/" target="_blank">
  <img src="{!$Resource.FlowLogo_Power_by}" value="www.salesforce.com"/> 
</a>
```